# "It is a duplicate"... Duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, flag-dialog

I was looking at this ["Give Me Teh Codez"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850653/vba-update-access-database-by-incoming-outlook-email) question and wanted to flag it, because it was clear there was no minimal understanding by the OP as to what he was doing.

When I went to flag it, I was prompted with this menu, which provided a checkbox for a duplicate question:
[image]

So, it wasn't a dupe and I selected the "It should be closed for another reason" button, and up popped this menu:
[image]

Is this by design, or is it an oversight?

Comment: Hmmmm.. never noticed that before

Comment: This duplicate duplicate is duplicate as well.

Comment: can't wait for this to be closed as duplicate

Comment: One more and we have a bad Michael Keaton movie...